# How to calculate expected value of having first collision of this password generator?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089081/calculating-the-probability-of-the-uuid-to-be-unique)

This is a password generator and it works as follow:

1. Define 3 set of characters: 0-9,  a-z, A-Z, and the password length $L$
2. Random pick one set of characters
3. From the picked set, random pick the character from it until $L$ length password is generated

Is it possible to calculate the expected number of times $n$ to generate same password which already geneated before? (password length $L$ is constant)

What struggle me the most is that the character set size is not the same, password formed by 0-9 is more likely to appear so the password is not equiprobable...

Comment: The setup is not clear to me. Do we pick each set with probability one third? And then do we pick all characters for the password from that same set?

Comment: Yes and yes, sorry for confusion

Comment: OK, one more question. The password we are trying to replicate. Is it given beforehand, or also chosen randomly. Or do we keep creating passwords and stop once we have generated a password that has been created before in the sequence?

Comment: The last case. And what is the expected number for it to happen?

Comment: @shole I think you have to fix a terminating condition, either: "in m attempts, the expected number of repeated passwords..." or "the expected number of attempts before (and including) the first repetition".

Comment: I think i meant your second condition, based on previous comments

Comment: It seems unlikely you will get a nice symbolic formula as a result for this expectation.

Comment: I think your question is a generalization of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people
There are $10^L$ and $26^L$ in the numerical and alphabetical sets respectively. So you may put $M = 10^L$, and multiply by $3$, to get the first match in numerical set. This should serve as an upper bound.